# adding controls supporting javascript into parent/containing page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, controls, templatefield

i have a asp.net page with a gridview in it, which is programatically (sp?) adding its columns. one of these is an itemtemplate, and it requires some javascript in the page to function.

is there any way from the template itself to add the required script into the containing page- obviously just the once, even thought the template will actually be output multiple times for each row of the grid

this is adding to the grid when the grid cols are being generated dynamically
here is the code that generates the cols

```
sub GenerateCols
.....
        Dim tActions = New TemplateField()
        tActions.HeaderText = "Actions"
        tActions.ItemTemplate = New CheckBoxActionTemplate()
        grd.Columns.Add(tActions)
....
 end sub
```

here is the template code

```
   public class CheckBoxActionTemplate : ITemplate
    {
        public CheckBoxActionTemplate() { }

        #region ITemplate Members

        public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
        {
            HtmlAnchor aAll = new HtmlAnchor();
            aAll.InnerText = "all";
            aAll.Attributes.Add("class", "all");

            HtmlAnchor aNone = new HtmlAnchor();
            aNone.InnerText = "none";
            aNone.Attributes.Add("class", "none");

            HtmlAnchor aInvert = new HtmlAnchor();
            aInvert.InnerText = "invert";
            aInvert.Attributes.Add("class", "invert");

            container.Controls.Add(aAll);
            container.Controls.Add(aNone);
            container.Controls.Add(aInvert);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

and here is the supporting javascript

```
 $("a.all").click( function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
        });
        return false;
    });

// Select none
    $("a.none").click( function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox').each(function(){
            $(this).removeAttr('checked');
        });
        return false;
    });


// Invert selection
    $("a.invert").click( function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox').each(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                $(this).removeAttr('checked');            
            }else{
               $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

along with that, if it was a control that appeared in a containing page multiple times, could the control also add its JS into the parent page itself, again just the once..?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the script to the page on the gridview load event for example

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" onload="GridView1_Load">
    </asp:GridView>
```

Then handle the event and write your script

```
protected void GridView1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();
        strScript.Append("<script language=JavaScript>");
        strScript.Append("$('a.all').click( function() {});//etc etc</script>");
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Pop", strScript.ToString());
    }
```